# How do i Change Create react app folder structure

Tags: reactjs, github, create-react-app

I have come across a situation where I need to change the folder structure of a react project which has been created using npx create-react-app. the reason to do this is I need to pull a part of the project (src folder and public folder) from a different GitHub repo. To do so I'm going to use the GitHub submodule. As far as I know, we can't use multiple folders pull from one repo with the GitHub submodule. So I need to put src and public folder into a new folder and make it a submodule.
what changes do I need to do in the react app in order to achieve this or is there any other option to get this done.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll just need to change the imports inside the components. If your App.jsx component for example uses a <Navigation> Component, you'd need to change the paths of that import

Answer (score 1):

[react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) enables changing some of Create React App's webpack config with a `config-overrides.js` file in your root directory. I imagine it'd be something like this for your case:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    paths: function (paths, env) {        
        paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'submodule/src/index.js');
        paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'submodule/src');
        paths.appPublic = path.resolve(__dirname, 'submodule/public'),
        paths.appHtml = path.resolve(__dirname, 'submodule/public/index.html'),
        return paths;
    },
}
```

There are [additional paths used by CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js), such as `testsSetup`, that may be relevant.